# MyLocationOverlay in osmdroid

Tags: android, mapping, location, osmdroid, mylocationoverlay

I'm working in an android mapping application using osmdroid mapping API, until now I'm being able to show the map(using MapView class) ,but I want to know how I can show my location on the map ,after I read about it I know that there is a class called MyLocationOverlay I'm trying to use it but the application return a blank page.here is my code:

```
public class AbodyActivity extends Activity 
{
private MapView mapView; 
private MapController mapController;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocationoverlay;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initializemap();
    myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myLocationoverlay.disableMyLocation(); // not on by default
    myLocationoverlay.disableCompass();
    myLocationoverlay.disableFollowLocation();
    myLocationoverlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);
    myLocationoverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            mapController.animateTo(myLocationoverlay
                    .getMyLocation());
        }
    });
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationoverlay);
}
public void initializemap()
{
mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK); 
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true); 
mapController = this.mapView.getController();     
mapController.setZoom(6);
}

}
```

and also here is the permissions which I used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that:

```
myLocationoverlay.disableMyLocation();
```

Doesn't disable the location finder methods so your `Runnable` is never called?

Comment: thanks Martin Pearman for your interesting .I am not understand your question ,but ma app is now working wright after i add these two lines to it:


        [myLocationoverlay.enableMyLocation();]

        [mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationoverlay);]